# Cypress Error when using POM and Commands with Cucumber framework

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-custom-commands

I'm facing an issue with my Cypress Cucumber tests using Page Object Model (POM), custom commands, and a data.json file. The test seems to skip the first When statement. Here's how my code is structured:

## Step-Def code:

```
import { When, Then, Given } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import homepage from '../../../pageObjects/homepage'

const HomePage = new homepage()

describe('Some Test', () => {
    let data; //closure variable
beforeEach(function()
{
    cy.fixture('cypressdata').then(function(fdata)
    {
        data=fdata;
    })
});
});

Given('I open home page', () => {
    cy.visit('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/')
})

When('I add products to cart', function () {
    // Product Page
        HomePage.shopmenu().click();
        this.data.product.forEach((element) => {
            cy.selectproduct(element);
        });
})

Then('validate the price', function () {
    it('calculate total price', function () {
        var sum = 0;
        cy.get("tr td:nth-child(4) strong").each(($el, index, $list) => {
            const Actualprice = $el.text();
            var result = Actualprice.split(" ");
            var result = result[1].trim();
            sum = Number(sum) + Number(result);
        }).then(function () {
            cy.log(sum);
        });

        var amt;
        cy.get('td[class="text-right"] h3 strong').then(function (element) {
            const totalamount = element.text();
            var amount = totalamount.split(" ");
            var amount = amount[1].trim();
            amt = Number(amount);
            expect(amt).to.be.equal(sum);
        }).then(function () {
            cy.log(amt);
        });

        it('click purchase button', function () {
            cy.get("button[class='btn btn-success']").click();
        });
    });
})

Then('select the country and submit and verify thank you message', function () {
    cy.get('#country').type('india');
    cy.get('div[class="suggestions"] ul li a').click();
    cy.get('#checkbox2').check({ force: true });
    cy.get('input[value*="Purchase"]').click();
    cy.get('.alert').then(function (element) {
        const AlertText = element.text();
        expect(AlertText.includes('Success')).to.be.true;
    });
})

When('I fill the form details', function () {
    it('fill form details', function () {
        HomePage.getEditbox().type(this.data.name);
        HomePage.getGender().select(this.data.gender).should('have.value', this.data.gender);
    });
})

Then('validate the form', function () {
    it('validate form details', function () {
        HomePage.twowayDataBind().should('have.value', this.data.name);
        HomePage.getEditbox().should('have.attr', 'minlength', '2');
        HomePage.empStatus().should('be.disabled');
    });
})

Then('select the shop page', function () {
    it('select the shop page', function () {
        HomePage.shopmenu().click();
    });
})
```

## beforeEach code:

```
describe('Some Test', () => {
    let data; //closure variable
beforeEach(function()
{
    cy.fixture('cypressdata').then(function(fdata)
    {
        data=fdata;
    })
});
});
```

## Feature file:

Feature: E2E Ecommerce Validation

```
Application Regression

Scenario: Ecommerce product delivery
    Given I open home page
    When I add products to cart
    Then validate the price
    Then select the country and submit and verify thank you message

Scenario: Filling the Home Page Form
    Given I open home page
    When I fill the form details
    Then validate the form
    Then select the shop page
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwpPk.png)

Issue Details
I suspect that the issue might be related to the setup or interaction between different components (POM, custom commands, data.json). However, I'm having difficulty identifying the root cause.

Additional Details:

Cypress version: ^13.5.1
Relevant dependencies:   "dependencies": {
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "latest",
"@cypress/browserify-preprocessor": "latest",
"cucumber": "^6.0.7",
"cypress-iframe": "^1.0.1"
}
Console output or error messages:

```
 Running:  ecommerce.feature                                                               (1 of 1)


  E2E Ecommerce Validation
    1) Ecommerce product delivery
    √ Filling the Home Page Form (183ms)


  1 passing (3s)
  1 failing

  1) E2E Ecommerce Validation
       Ecommerce product delivery:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'product')
      at Context.eval (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\examples\BDD\ecommerce.feature:15805:19)
      at Registry.runStepDefininition (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\examples\BDD\ecommerce.feature:8554:48)
      at Object.fn (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\examples\BDD\ecommerce.feature:15015:43)
      at runStepWithLogGroup (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\examples\BDD\ecommerce.feature:14627:29)
      at Context.eval (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\examples\BDD\ecommerce.feature:15011:62)
```

Steps Taken
Checked the configuration of custom commands.
Verified that the data.json file is correctly loaded.
Reviewed the POM structure to ensure proper page element selection.

Request for Assistance
I would greatly appreciate any help in identifying the problem and resolving the issue. If you need more specific information or if there are additional steps I should take, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'product')*** refers to this line.

```js
this.data.product.forEach((element)
```

This means that the part `this.data` is the part that is undefined.

You can fix it in the following ways:

- by dropping `this` and use `data.product.forEach((element)` since `let data` does not put the data variable of `this` scope.

  ```js
  let data;
  beforeEach(function() {
    cy.fixture('cypressdata').then(function(fdata) {
      data = fdata;
    })
  ...

  When('I add products to cart', function () {
    ...
    data.product.forEach((element) => {
      cy.selectproduct(element);
  ...
  ```

- by setting an alias `cy.fixture('cypressdata').as('data')` which will set the variable `data` on `this` scope

  ```js
  let data;
  beforeEach(function() {
    cy.fixture('cypressdata').as('data')
  })
  ...

  When('I add products to cart', function () {
    ...
    this.data.product.forEach((element) => {
      cy.selectproduct(element);
  ...
  ```

- by moving `cy.fixture()` inside `When()` and get rid of `beforeEach()`

  ```js
  When('I add products to cart', function () {
    cy.fixture('cypressdata').then(data => {
      data.product.forEach((element) => {
  ```